# Heroku add-ons - Credit card required

Tags: heroku

i am trying to add this add-on:

`heroku addons:create jawsdb-maria:kitefin`

It's free, but I receive this answer:

`heroku addons:create jawsdb-maria:kitefin                                                                                               Creating jawsdb-maria:kitefin on ⬢ .... !`
`!    Please verify your account to install this add-on plan (please enter a credit card) For more information...`

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some add ons (even when free) require you to have a verified account. You verify by adding a credit card.

I've been verified on Heroku for many years now and have never spent any money on it.

You can read their official stance on it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification

> **When is verification required?**
>   You must verify your account if you, or
>   collaborators of your app, want to:
>
> - Use more than one dyno in the app.
> - Add any add-on to the app, even if the add-on is free. The only exceptions to this are the free plans for the Heroku Postgres and Heroku Connect add-ons, which can be used without verification.
> - Add a custom domain to the app.
> - Receive the transfer of an app that has paid resources.
> - Exceed default one-off dyno limits on the app.
> - Have more than 5 apps at a time. Verified accounts may have up to 100 apps.